# Understanding subviews frame in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have the following code where I'm trying to dynamically add subviews to a UIScrollView.. However, the result is not what I've expected. Here it is:

```
let red = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
red.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let blue = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200))
blue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
blue.addSubview(red)
view.addSubview(blue)
```

[image]

Why on earth is the red square not at the top left corner of the scroll view like I expected...? How can I make it happen?

Comment: I created a dummy project with Xcode, pasted your code in viewDidLoad and it works. Can you share whole view controller code?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Try to comment out the line that defines the view `red` and see where else is this view referenced